# PHP Arrays to JSON without []

Tags: javascript, php, json, mapbox, geojson

I am using a CMS, and want to pass some PHP arrays to JSON. I am managing to do this fine but the issue is that it wraps [] round the array, whereas I need it without [] to use it as geojson within Mapbox (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/).

```
<?php 
$programme_array = array();
$programmes = $pages->find('parent=programme, sort=sort');
foreach ($programmes as $programme) {
    $title = $programme->title;
    $url = $programme->url;
    $summary = $programme->programme_summary;
    $image = $programme->programme_venue_image->url;
    $long = $programme->programme_location->lng;
    $lat = $programme->programme_location->lat;
    $programme_array[] = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'Point',
            'coordinates' => [$long,$lat]
        ),
        'properties' => array(
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $summary,
            'image' => $image,
            'url' => $url,
            "marker-symbol" => "music"
        ),
    );

}
$programme_json = json_encode($programme_array, true);
?>

[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["-1.466439","53.376842"]},"properties":{"title":"Site Gallery","description":"Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Donec id justo. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Suspendisse feugiat. Etiam rhoncus.","image":"\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/site\/assets\/files\/1032\/site_gallery.jpg","url":"\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/programme\/site-gallery\/","marker-symbol":"music"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["-1.477881","53.374798"]},"properties":{"title":"Moore Street Substation","description":"","image":null,"url":"\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/programme\/moore-street-substation\/","marker-symbol":"music"}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["-1.459620","53.380562"]},"properties":{"title":"S1 Artspace","description":"","image":null,"url":"\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/programme\/s1-artspace\/","marker-symbol":"music"}}]
```

**UPDATE**

I have come up with the following, which works in terms of formatting BUT it's only returning one item and not three?

```
$geojson = array( 'type' => 'FeatureCollection', 'features' => array());

$programmes = $pages->find('parent=programme, sort=sort');
foreach ($programmes as $programme) {

  $marker = array(
    'type' => 'Feature',
    'properties' => array(
      'title' => $programme->title,
      "marker-symbol" => "music"
    ),
    'geometry' => array(
      'type' => 'Point',
      'coordinates' => array( 
        $programme->programme_location->lng,
        $programme->programme_location->lat
      )
    )
  );
  array_push($geojson['features'], $marker);
}
$programme_json = json_encode($marker, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

What's even weirder is that if I add the square brackets `[ ]` to `$marker = array(` effectively making it `$marker[] = array(` then it returns all the items BUT it has the square brackets on it.

I'm so deep down the rabbit hole...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with after much trial and error.

```
<?php 

$geojson = array(
    'type' => 'FeatureCollection', 
    'features' => array()
);

$programmes = $pages->find('parent=programme, sort=sort');
foreach ($programmes as $programme) {

    $marker = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'properties' => array(
            'title' => $programme->title,
            'url' => $programme->url,
            'summary' => $programme->programme_summary,
            'image' => $programme->programme_venue_image->url
        ),
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'Point',
            'coordinates' => array( 
                $programme->programme_location->lng,
                $programme->programme_location->lat
            )
        )
    );
    array_push($geojson['features'], $marker);

}
$programme_json = json_encode($geojson);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please convert array to object before you encode it to json which should remove the []. Hope that helps!!

Remove the [] from the variable $programme_array[], so it should look like `$programme_array = array(......................);` and it will do the job. In fact, you do not need to say $programme_array[] as you have initialising it as $programme_array = array().

Comment: I did try `$programme_array = (object) $programme_array;
$programme_json = json_encode($programme_array, true);` but it adds `"0":`, for example which I do not need.

Comment: Remove the [] from the variable $programme_array[], so it should look like $programme_array = array(......................); and it will do the job. In fact, you do not need to say $programme_array[] as you have initialising it as $programme_array = array().

Comment: When I did this it only returned the last item from the array... not them all?

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you post your return script?

Comment: `{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["-1.459620","53.380562"]},"properties":{"title":"S1 Artspace","description":"","image":null,"url":"\/Freelance\/art-sheffield-2016\/programme\/s1-artspace\/","marker-symbol":"music"}}    });`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use arrays where appropriate not where you need objects. When you need objects you can use `stdClass`. Here's how to create a PHP structure that encodes perfectly to JSON:

```
<?php

$feature = new stdClass();
$feature->type = 'Feature';
$feature->properties = new stdClass();
$feature->properties->key = 'value';
$feature->geometry = new stdClass();
$feature->geometry->type = 'Point';
$feature->geometry->coordinates = array(0,0);

$json = json_encode($feature);
```

Here `$json` holds:

```
"{"type":"Feature","properties":{"key":"value"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[0,0]}}"
```

When you send it to the client and parse that in Javascript it turns into:

```
{
    "type":"Feature",
    "properties": {
         "key":"value"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type":"Point",
        "coordinates":[0,0]
    }
}
```

So now when you create a GeoJSON collection object:

```
<?php

$collection = new stdClass();
$collection->type = 'FeatureCollection';
$collection->features = array();
```

You can push the `$feature` into `$collection->features`:

```
$collection->features[] = $feature;
```

Answer (score 0):

@braw, please check the below code.

```
$programmes = array('1', '2');
$programme_array = array();
foreach ($programmes as $programme) {

    $programme_array[] = array(
        'type' => 'Feature',
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'Point',
            'coordinates' => ['$long', '$lat']
        ),
        'properties' => array(
            'title' => '$title',
            'description' => '$description',
            'image' => '$image',
            'url' => '$url',
            "marker-symbol" => "music"
        ),
    );
}
```

Output here:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [type] => Feature
            [geometry] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Point
                    [coordinates] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => $long
                            [1] => $lat
                        )

                )

            [properties] => Array
                (
                    [title] => $title
                    [description] => $description
                    [image] => $image
                    [url] => $url
                    [marker-symbol] => music
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [type] => Feature
            [geometry] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Point
                    [coordinates] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => $long
                            [1] => $lat
                        )

                )

            [properties] => Array
                (
                    [title] => $title
                    [description] => $description
                    [image] => $image
                    [url] => $url
                    [marker-symbol] => music
                )

        )

)
```

Run the below code to see the json output without[].

```
echo json_encode( (object) $programme_array );
```

Output:

```
{"0":{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["$long","$lat"]},"properties":{"title":"$title","description":"$description","image":"$image","url":"$url","marker-symbol":"music"}},"1":{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":["$long","$lat"]},"properties":{"title":"$title","description":"$description","image":"$image","url":"$url","marker-symbol":"music"}}}
```

Comment: Yes but if you remove [ ] from $programme_array[], you only get one item returned...

Comment: isn't above scipt did solve your problem as it prints the json value without [].

Comment: Can you please provide how you got to the json without the [] ?

Comment: Check above as I have updated the answer! Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get [] in a json without them is doing this:

//$json is your json without []
//$data an empty array

$data[]=$json;
print_r($data); // your $data is now a json with []